# comparing hebrew strings in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, hebrew

I'm writing a small scirpt that will give me some updates from an israel cable company website written in Hebrew (html). The web page uses abbreviation which I want to change back to the full word. I have placed a line at the head of my python file

```
#coding=utf8
```

and a line in the code

```
if w = "ה.": print (w)
```

but I get a warning:

> wm.py:26: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert
>   both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal   if w
>   == "ה.": print (w)

So I tried to put the abbreviation in a file and load them from there but the keys are loaded as `\xd7\x94.'` and not as the Hebrew letters (And the compraison fails)

So, how can I compare the strings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to mark it as a unicode string:

```
if w == u"ה.": print (w)
```

That's gonna work now.

**EDIT:** Let me state the obvious: the variable `w` should also be a unicode string (`w = u"..."`).

Answer (score 2):

It helps to post a complete example illustrating the problem, along with the version of Python you are using.  For example, `print(w)` usually implies Python 3, but works in Python 2 as well.

I reproduced your error with the following code on Python 2.7.  Note that the `coding` line is declaring the *source file encoding*, so the file must be saved as UTF-8 from an editor that supports it.

```
#coding=utf8  
w = u'ה.'
if w == "ה.":
    print (w)
```

Result:

```
C:\y.py:3: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if w == "ה.":
```

The problem occurs when comparing Unicode strings with byte strings.  Python attempts to coerce the byte string to a Unicode string using the default "ascii" codec, the the byte string is actually encoded in UTF-8 according to the source encoding.  Always make sure to compare Unicode strings to Unicode strings and byte strings to byte strings:

To fix, mark the string as Unicode:

```
if w == u"ה.":
```